# Remove shared devices from my MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, network

Some device is being shown under **Shared** section on my MacBook. I don't remember setting up any such device at all.

[image: Shared device]

How do I remove this device, once and for all? Note that I am not sharing any folder, etc. Also, right clicking, etc. does not reveal any options.

Comment: Seems that this computer is on your network. You can hide this from Finder Preferences. You cannot remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device you see under **Shared** section in Finder sidebar is not the computer you setup. In your case, that's a Windows computer with some form of sharing enabled.

If you do not access resources available in your local Network this way, you can choose to remove the **Shared** section from the Finder sidebar. Just open Finder Preferences, go to Sidebar tab and uncheck all the items shown under **Shared** section.

[image]

Comment: Well, how did you find out that it was a _Windows_ device?  And secondly, how do I ensure that I am not sharing anything with it?  _I_ remember I haven't setup any sharing myself, but I would like to double check once if anything is being shared, just for security reasons.  Any way to check that?

Comment: It's a prank. macOS shows the icon representing shared Windows PC as  14" CRT with Blue Screen of Death. To ensure that you are not sharing anything, check System Preferences → Sharing. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/blue-screen-of-death-for-windows-network-icons.378638/

Comment: I don't think it's *necessarily* a Windows device, just a device using network protocols usually used by Windows computers. It could be a printer, NAS or other networked gadget.